# Angular 4 form state changes after second key stoke in input control

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I would like save user's data each time the input control is changed. But I do not want to save when the page gets loaded. Here is my code:

HTML page:

```
<form  [formGroup]="singleTextForm">
  <mat-form-field class="text-box-width">
    <input matInput placeholder=""  formControlName="AnswersResponses" [ngModel]="AnswersResponses?.answerText" (ngModelChange)="save($event, AnswersResponses)" />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is my typescript code:

```
save(event, profileResponse: GetAnswersResponses) {

if (!this.singleTextForm.pristine){  
     // save code
   };
}
```

It works great except that the this.singleTextForm.pristine state doesn't get updated until the second key stroke. So if the user wants to update only one character the application will not save it.

Thanks

**WORKING SOLUTION**

So I took AJT_82 solution with some updates. Here is the code that I used:

HTML page:

```
<form  [formGroup]="singleTextForm">
  <mat-form-field class="text-box-width">    
     <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="AnswersResponses (input)="save(AnswersResponses)" [value]="AnswersResponses.answerText" />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is my typescript code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.singleTextForm.patchValue({
        AnswersResponses: this.AnswersResponses
          })
}
...

save(profileResponse: GetAnswersResponses) {

      profileResponse.answerText = this.singleTextForm.value["AnswersResponses"].toString();

  //save change to database
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this up a bit and make full use of the reactive form, and thereby drop the `ngModel` altogether. If you are receiving the data to the **variable** `AnswersResponses` (not formcontrol), you can use `patchValue` or `setValue` to set the value to your **form control** when you receive your data:

```
this.singleTextForm.patchValue({
  AnswersResponses: this.AnswersResponses.answerText
})
```

Then we can remove the `ngModelChange` and instead listen `input` of user:

```
<input matInput formControlName="AnswersResponses" (input)="save()" />
```

and TS:

```
save() {
 console.log(this.singleTextForm.value)
}
```

*As a sidenote, if you are making a http-call for saving, you might want to change this a bit more and listen to the change of the formcontrol with `valueChanges` and use `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged`, for example for the use case if user types really fast to not make "unnecessary" http-calls.*

Comment: So I finally got it to work but I had to modify your code in order to pass the object not just the text (I'm still learning), see my updated question. As for you sidenote, I thought of it but I have no idea how to do it, would you be able to direct me to a site with a working example? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a demo for you, choose the debounce time you want, make http-request (commented out) and subscribe! :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uk8gln?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if it's dirty or not. `!this.singleTextForm.dirty`

Comment: This answer gave me the same result as my problem